# Highlighting active navigation item

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I am either having a brain fart or just going about this completely wrong, can someone please poing me in the right direction. I just want to add the active class to the active link.

```
<ul id="navigtaion" class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="home"><a href="{{ action('HomeController@getHome') }}">home</a></li>
    <li class="news"><a href="{{ action('NewsController@getIndex') }}">news</a></li>        
</ul>



$(document).ready(function(){
    url = window.location.pathname;
    url = url.substring(1);
    if(url==''){
        url = 'home';
    }
    $('#navigation li.active').removeClass('active');  
    $('#navigation li').each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass(url)){
            $(this).addClass('active'); 
        }
    });    
});
```

Comment: `id="navigtaion"` typo?

Comment: You know I just seen that and came back to delete this post. Thanks for the second set of eyes, I was beating my head on the desk.

Answer (score 2):

I have a typing error in the id for the ul. Sorry for wasting everyones time.